# delete data based on company_id and year from database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to delete data based on company_id and year from my database.
[image]

sample data content

[image]

my model in App\Models, I've added the company_id and year to be for the primary key

```
class CompanyMasterCuti extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'company_master_cuti';
    protected $fillable = [
        'company_id', 'year', 'cuti', 'created', 'created_by', 'modified', 'modified_by', 
    ];
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = ['company_id', 'year'];
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function company() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Company', 'company_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

my code in controller

```
    public function delete_master_cuti($company_id, $year) {

        $master_cuti = CompanyMasterCuti::where('company_id', $company_id)->where('year', $year)->first();

        $master_cuti->delete();

        toast('Success', 'success');
        return redirect()->route('master-cuti.index');

    }
```

index.blade.php, in this code I've added the requested company_id and year to delete the data, but this method still doesn't work

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#master_cuti_ids').val($(this).data('company_id','year')); $('#deleteModalBu').modal('show');">
         <li class="badge-circle badge-circle-light-secondary bx bxs-trash font-medium-1 text-danger my-1"></i>
 </a>
```

[image]

form action to delete function delete data in index.blade.php

```
   <form id="form-edit" action="{{ route('delete_master_cuti', [$m_cuti->company_id, $m_cuti->year] ) }}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <input type="hidden" id="company_id" name="company_id">
                            <input type="hidden" id="year" name="year">

                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"
                                        style="width: 100%;">
                                        <i class="bx bx-x d-block d-sm-none"></i>
                                        <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Cancel</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger ml-1" style="width: 100%">
                                        <i class="bx bx-check d-block d-sm-none"></i>
                                        <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Delete</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </form>
```

my route

```
    Route::post('delete_master_cuti/{company_id}/{year}', [CompanyMasterCutiController::class, 'delete_master_cuti'])->name('delete_master_cuti');
```

I get error: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. Please help me

Comment: Half of what you posted is irrelevant to the error you reported. Since you get, `MethodNotAllowedHttpException The GET method is not supported for this route` you need to see why you are calling the route with GET and not with POST. Maybe you have some JS linked to your delete button that runs an ajax query in GET method. (the reste, database/controller/model are irrelevant since the request never reaches them)